# SharePoint 2010 List View webpart XSLT

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to create a custom display of a list view web part using XSLT. I have linked to a xsl file and populated it with the following code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">    
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table class="ms-listviewtable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="100%" border="0">     
        <thead>
           <th class="ms-vh2">Title</th>
           <th class="ms-vh2">Status</th>
           <th class="ms-vh2">Percent Complete</th>
        </thead>      
    </table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Row">
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/> 
        </td> 
        <td> 
            <xsl:value-of select="@Status"/> 
        </td> 
        <td> 
            <xsl:value-of select="@PercentComplete"/> 
        </td> 
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

It is only display the headings at the moment. Can someone point out what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call your `Row` template. In coding terms, you effectively have a Row method that is never called by your Main.

Try adding [xsl:apply-templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256184%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to your root template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table class="ms-listviewtable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="100%" border="0">     
        <thead>
           <th class="ms-vh2">Title</th>
           <th class="ms-vh2">Status</th>
           <th class="ms-vh2">Percent Complete</th>
        </thead>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems kinda stupid of me now that i see your answer. It works fine now.